# Date to string conversion

Tags: vb.net, string, date

```
Dim data1 As String
Dim conn1 As SqlConnection
Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand
Dim ada1 As New SqlDataAdapter()
Dim ds1 As New DataSet

data1 = lbldmdate.Text.ToString()
conn1 = New SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=false;User Id=justin;Data Source=ARULJUSTIN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=firemaintain;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False")
conn1.Open()
ada1 = New SqlDataAdapter("select Recordno, uhnumber,uhbuilding,uhlocation from hydrantmaintain WHERE unndate= '" & Today.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy") & "'", conn)

ada1.Fill(ds1)
dgnxtmdates.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
```

I am getting an error: "cannot convert from date to string"

Comment: When do you get the error? Compile time? Run time? If so is it from `ToString` function (I dont think so), or Ado.NET components? Or from database? Which line? Your question may get closed with this level of information.

Comment: I get a compile time error sql exception "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Comment: Justin, that's runtime exception, not compile time..

Comment: fine actually I am struct with this code I need to fill a dataset using select where date = today.

Comment: which line? Can you post the complete error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Nawful pointed out, you are using "mm" (minutes) instead of "MM" (months) but it also looks like you month and day are reversed. Now, this is dependant upon your region settings for dates and specifically how you configured the SQL server but to avoid these issues, I like to do this for dates:

```
CONVERT(datetime, '" & Format(Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & " 00:00:00', 102)
```

and this for Date and Time:

```
CONVERT(datetime, '" & Format(Value, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss") & "', 126)
```

Note, `Value` is a date or datetime data type.

In your example, it would be something like this:

```
ada1 = New SqlDataAdapter("select Recordno, uhnumber,uhbuilding,uhlocation from hydrantmaintain WHERE unndate= CONVERT(datetime, '" & Format(Today, "yyyy-MM-dd") & " 00:00:00', 102)", conn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to point out, but your string formatting should be `dd/MM/yy`. `mm` corresponds to minutes component.

```
Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

If **unndate** is the `datetime` data type in the database, you don't need to convert `Today` to string when querying the database.

Cause, `Today` is already a `DateTime`.

But, if **unndate** is a string datatype, varchar or nvarchar for example, my only advice is to use the datatype `datetime` for the unndate value in the first place if you want to query like that.

Comment: undate is a date data type in the data base. when trying to fill the data set with a select statement i am getting an error error sql exception "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Comment: @Justin - if unndate is a date data type in the database, then as Ye Mon points out, you don't need to call ToString and your query should not contain single quotes around the date time value.