# ADO - Different Date Formats in VB and SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, date-format

Im executing this query in VB:

```
 Dim str As String = "select date_created from TABLE_DATES group by date_created"
 Dim cm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(str, cn)
 ..
```

It's returning the following field in **VB**:

```
'11/7/2013 4:30:44 PM'
```

While in SQL the same field is:

```
'2013-11-07 16:30:44.917'
```

So when I send the date from VB to SQL in a query condition, SQL doesn't find the row I asked for.

Any solution to this?

Comment: Dates are not stored in any format in Sql Server.  Don't use strings to hold dates, use a DateTime variable and then when you display the day, format it however you wish.  Your search should work with a DateTime variable as well.

Comment: Avoid forcing either VB or SQL to treat dates as *strings* - those are the things that *have* formatting issues. VB.Net has access to a `DateTime` type - SQL database systems have appropriate types (either `datetime` or `datetime2`, for SQL Server, for instance). And ADO.Net knows how to take a .NET `DateTime` and convert it to the appropriate database type - all without ever treating these values as a string. So just use parameters and be happy

Comment: @ChrisDunaway the query with all the dates is filling a DataAdapter that is binding a listbox..

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm filling a Listbox with this query and then using every field individually therefore they are converted to String variables. How to do this?

Comment: It's only the format, the data is the same.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The data is the same, but when the format is different I can't send back the variables to SQL in a condition *where date=..*

Comment: @HelpASisterOut Of course you can (use SQL parameters, that's what you need anyway; once you switch to using parameters, the format differences become irrelevant). You probably shouldn't be comparing datetime objects for equality, but that is a different question.

Comment: We are telling you that you should not send a string that looks as a date to the database engine. Your items are strings used to represent the datetime value extracted. When you query back your database you should take that string representation and convert it back to a date and pass that value using a parameterized query.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight When asked to sort fields and display them according to their date, I have no other option.

Comment: @HelpASisterOut Why? Ordering by date works perfectly regardless of whether it is done inside or outside the RDBMS.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight After displaying the date in a listbox, the user picks one date, and then I have to display all the records that were inserted in that date. So the only option I have is selecting fields depending on their date_created.

Comment: @Steve It fixes the format of the date, but the how to convert '4:30:44 PM'' to 16:30:44.917' ?

Comment: @HelpASisterOut That's the thing: do not convert it, pass it as a date object. You need to store the exact date behind the list box item, otherwise the time isn't going to match. Create a query with a `@UserSelectedTime` parameter, set it to the `DateTime` object from the list box, and send it to SQL like that. You will get back your row.

Comment: Don't use string, you don't need to convert. Use DateTime. I'll assume that when you query the database you concatonate your query, use SqlParameters. Show us the code that has the date problem.

Comment: I already upvoted some of the comments above, and I just want to add my name under list of people who advise against converting date to string and back. You can have an Object as a ValueMember of DataSource, so it can be a DateTime. If you are thinking about DisplayMember, you can convert to some representation. However, the value will stay untouched with this approach.

Answer (score -1):

See my answer [to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418617/date-to-string-conversion/19432989#19432989) that will help you ensure your date is always in the correct format. What you do with it, is your decision.